# Starting a new django project on qpython

Tags: django, qpython

I have installed qpydjango on my android phone and the sample project works perfectly. I have been trying start a new project(django website) but have not succeeded.
I've tried running "django-admin.py startproject mysite" but I get this error

> `syntax error or django is not defined`.

Comment: Is it syntax or sintax?

Comment: Hi Idris, thanks for the quick response. it's Syntax

Comment: If this is on your Android phone, maybe check out the [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/) exchange

Comment: Some one please give a working solution

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't gotten any answer from anyone I come up with the following in case anyone has the same question.

```
#qpy:console
import os
import os.path

projectname=raw_input("Enter project name: ")
projectdir="/mnt/sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/projects/"+projectname

if os.path.exists(projectdir):
    print "sorry project '"+projectname+"' already exists"
else:
    print "Starting django project '"+projectname+"'"
    os.makedirs(projectdir)
    os.system("cd /mnt/sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin && python django-admin.py startproject "+projectname+" "+projectdir)

    appname=raw_input("Enter your first app name: ")
    print  "Starting the first django app '"+appname+"'"
    os.system("cd "+projectdir+" && python manage.py startapp "+appname)

    print "You project and first app started successfully"
    print "Find the project here '"+projectdir+"'"
    print " and edit settings.py as necessory"
    print " then run python manage.py runserver to start"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

download this version of django using pip.

```
pip install django==1.8.16
```

It works for me